# Classicthesis + texlive fresh install

Tags: texlive, installing, classicthesis

I have been using TeX Live on Ubuntu 14.04 and the package classicthesis with no problems until now.

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and TeX Live with it. I followed the guide on how to install "vanilla" TeX Live (very good guide).

But this very simple piece of code had a problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Indeed the page number and "test" are written on the top right corner, which is not the normal behaviour of classicthesis.

What should I do?

EDIT : here is the file list

```
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
classicthesis.sty    2015/09/06 v4.2 Typographic style for a classic-looking th
esis
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
dvipsnam.def    2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
mathpazo.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
 ot1pplj.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for OT1/pplj.
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
    soul.sty    2003/11/17 v2.4 letterspacing/underlining (mf)
scrlayer-scrpage.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (end user interface for scrlayer)
scrlayer.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (defining layers and page styles)
titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
 tocloft.sty    2013/05/02 v2.3f parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
 scrtime.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (time of LaTeX run)
remreset.sty    
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
    test.out
    test.out
supp-pdf.mkii
  mt-ppl.cfg    2005/11/16 v1.6 microtype config. file: Palatino (RS)

 ot1pplx.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for OT1/pplx.
 omlzplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OML/zplm.
 omszplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMS/zplm.
 omxzplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMX/zplm.
 ot1zplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
```

Comment: I get what sounds like the output you describe, so I'm not sure if 'this is not normal' really applies. In any case, can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the `File list` this generates in your log into the question.

Comment: With `classicthesis` you should always set the page parameters, in this case with `geometry`.

Comment: Is tehre any news here? I get the expected output.